# Orthogonal complement of complex subspace

Tags: orthogonality

I have a dot product defined by a matrix
$$
A= \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1+i \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    1-i & -1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and I want to find an orthogonal complement of a subspace 
$$W=span\{(-i,1,1+i),(-1-i,1,3)\}$$

I think I need to find the null space of $$W.A=0$$
where W is a matrix with row vectors $$(-i,1,1+i)(-1-i,1,3)$$.

The thing is, I am not sure whether to conjugate the vectors of subspace first or not,  as I tried and my complement ended up being $$(-3-3i,i,1)$$ but it doesn't seem right.

Can someone give me a general idea how to solve otrthogonal complement of complex subspace when the dot product is defined by a orthogonal matrix?

Comment: The starting point is: what does it means that a dot product is defined by a matrix?  What is your answer?

Comment: Matrix is a mapping, so the matrix that defines a dot vector is a mapping of two vectors that give us a number. So the standard dot product is defined by identity matrix.

I'm sorry I am not a native english speaker so using the verb define is maybe not used with matrixes.

Answer (score 1):

Given an hermitian positive definite matrix , as your $A$, the corresponding inner product on $\mathbb{C}^3$ is the Hermitian form defined as
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=y^\dagger A x
$$
where $y^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $y$.

So in your case you have to found a vector $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)^T$ such that:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\overline{y_1}&\overline{y_2}&\overline{y_3}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1+i \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    1-i & -1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-i\\1\\1+i
\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\overline{y_1}&\overline{y_2}&\overline{y_3}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1+i \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    1-i & -1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1-i\\1\\3
\end{pmatrix}
=0
$$

The  searched orthogonal complement subspace is the span of this vector $y$.

Comment: Thank you so very much :)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am confused as the complement is now even less likely (-19+9i/3,-i,3).